# Java inner classes & inheritance: Is there a duplicate outer this reference?

Tags: java, inheritance, language-lawyer, inner-classes

Consider this scenario with inner classes and inheritance:

```
class X{
    class A{
       X foo(){
           return X.this; // outer this reference to X returned
       }
    }

}

class Y extends X{
    class B extends A {
       Y foo(){
           return Y.this; // outer this reference to Y returned
       }
    }
}
```

How does the memory layout of class `B` look like? Does it have two outer `this` references which both point to the same object? Or does it have only one outer `this` reference. What is the type of this reference?

The reason why I ask: I have a more or less deep hierarchy that uses nested classes like this. If the outer `this` reference was replicated for each level of inheritance, then I should maybe think over this design.

In addition, I am just curious about this design detail of the Java programming language.

---

I used `javap` to check the layout: The `this` pointer is really replicated

```
class X$A {
  final X this$0; // <-- first reference
  X$A(X);
  X foo();
}

class Y$B extends X$A {
  final Y this$0; // <-- second reference
  Y$B(Y);
  Y foo();
  X foo();
}
```

Comment: What is an "outer this pointer?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose the implicit reference that every inner class has to it's parent instance, in this case `X.this` and `Y.this`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Renamed to "outer this reference". Added some examples in the code.

Comment: @OP, why do you care about replication or otherwise of pointers?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: The inner classes are instanciated very often (a few ten million times). I do not want to pay the space overhead for a lot of extra implicit this references.

Comment: You need to code up some of these examples, and let the compiler tell you why they won't compile.  I think you're too worried about "implicit this references;" if you need the classes, then you need them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What do you mean? The code I posted compiles fine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: They do compile.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: If you're worried about the pointer, just make it a nested class rather than an inner class. If you cannot do this - then you obviously _need_ the pointer so the discussion is moot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: See the last paragraph of my question. That is the (possible) problem. In addition, I am trying to learn a few new inner workings of Java.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the OP is concerned that the implicit references will take up space unnecessarily. I think you're being a little aggressive.

Comment: Well, there's no way for us to evaluate your design without seeing more of your code than simply foo bar baz.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I am trying, in my own little way, to say that concern about implicit references taking up space is an arbitrary concern.  If there are millions of these things, I doubt that `this` matters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I tried to condense my code to a minimal working example to not overkill you with a wall of code. Just think of classes like these with 4 layers of inheritance. The inner classes do use the outer ones and get instanciated a few ten million times.

Comment: Yes, but without some context, there's no way for us to advise you.  We don't know *why* you need millions of instances with 4 layers of inheritance, or why these classes need to be nested, for that matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: But the OP isn't asking for advice, he's asking a specific technical question (whether there are multiple `this` refs per object).

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed. Without context we cannot possibly answer. If a class _needs_ to be an inner class then that's what it needs to be. It's like needing to store a 64bit number and complaining that `long` takes up too much space.

Comment: As with any optimization, the first thing to do is _measure._ Have you yet observed that these instances are using too much memory? Have you compared memory usage across different class structures?

Comment: Agreed with Matt Ball.  Make a million instances, and measure.  Find out if this is an actual problem or not.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - of course we can answer, the question is very simple (it's not asking for design advice).  (As it happens, I don't know the answer.)

Comment: You don't need to measure here - you can use `javap` to see how many fields there are. I'm looking in the JLS to see what that says, but I'm finding it hard to find anything for this specific situation. It does feel like a *very* convoluted design to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Okay, see the last paragraph I added. I just want to know whether Java replicates the `this` pointer in this case, be it for just curiousity about language details like this. I want no advise, just an answer whether Java mandates that there will be more than one `this` pointer per instance. Measuring only tells me how my VM handles this. I am rather looking for a statement from the specification which will be true for all VMs.

Comment: Note that the JVM does not provide strict guarantees about the memory layout it uses. One of the benefits of doing so is that _there are multiple different ways to do it._ For instance, [you can set `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` which uses a rather different pointer implementation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)

Comment: There is only one `this` pointer per object.  Does that answer your question?  Nested classes don't count as additional `this` pointers, only instances.  Nor do inherited classes; they get folded in as part of the main object structure when the outer class is instantiated.  Memory layout is an internal implementation detail, and probably not relevant to your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, there is more than one outer `this` pointer stored in every object of type `B`. See the latest edit to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `javap` to find out what fields a class has. (This is up to the compiler, not the JVM.) In this case:

```
C:\Users\Jon\Test>javap -p Y$B
Compiled from "Test.java"
class Y$B extends X$A {
  final Y this$0;
  Y$B(Y);
  Y foo();
  X foo();
}
```

So as you can see, there's one reference to an enclosing instance of `Y` - but `X$A` will also have a reference to the enclosing instance of `X` (which you can verify with `javap -p X$A` if you want). So yes, the object will have two fields in total for enclosing instances.

You can use `javap -c Y$B` to see the body of the constructor, which shows that the enclosing `Y` instance reference is then passed up to the constructor of `X.A` as the enclosing `X` instance reference - confirming that the two fields will have the same value.

However, I haven't yet found out where in the JLS this is addressed. In itself, this is a cause for concern - if you're in a situation which is hard to explain with the JLS, that's a pretty good hint that other developers may not be able to follow what's going on either. This feels like a convoluted design to me... unless you really *need* all these nested classes, I'd try to avoid them.

Comment: So this would indeed mean this design has quite some disadvantages. Maybe I should make only the uppermost class an inner class, make the subclasses instead static nested classes and simply write an "outer this getter method" in the topmost class that will allow the subclasses to get the outer this field.

Comment: @gexicide: Well I'd try to get inner classes out of the picture entirely if I were you. If you've got a deep inheritance chain, that's complex enough without having inner classes involved. Do you need access to *private* members of the enclosing instance? If not, I'd just declare top-level classes and use composition where you need it. It'll make it *much* clearer what's going on, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think each inner class in the inheritance hierarchy has it's own "outer this" reference because B can have a constructor like

```
    public B(X a) {
        a.super();
    }
```

So that you can do

```
X x = new X();
Y y = new Y();
Y.B b = y.new B(x);
```

Now you have an instance of Y.B where the foo() method returns y, yet the original foo method in A returns x!